# how to implement a mini game using spritekit within an already developed project

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uikit, swift5

the problem is how to represent the spritekit scene inside the view controller

```
public class GameScene: SKScene {
```

I was thinking of doing it with a public class, but I don't know how to get it started, I just started to progam

Comment: Just start a new sprite kit project and see what they do......

Answer (score 0):

This is the initialisation of an SKScene inside a UIViewController.

```
import SpriteKit

class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sceneView = SKView(frame: view.frame)
        view.addSubview(sceneView)

        let scene = SKScene()
        sceneView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

To open this screen you simply use the modal/navigationController presentation from the parent screen:

```
navigationController.push(SomeViewController(), animated: true)
```

or

```
present(SomeViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```